Unable to connect to server: connection failed: connection refused is the server running that host Postgres with Docker
I'm currently using Docker Desktop and I'm encountering an issue with my database. I have been able to use the pgAdmin container without any problems. However, when I attempt to connect the server to the database, I get an error.
Unfortunately, I haven't been able to determine the cause of this issue. I would appreciate any assistance or suggestions on how to resolve this problem. Thank you in advance for your help.

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:
version: '3'

services:
  myDB:
    image: postgres:16
    container_name: my-database
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=alumno
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456
      - POSTGRES_DB=course-db
    volumes:
      - ./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  
  pdAdmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    container_name: pgadmin4
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - myDB
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    user: '$UID:$GID'
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=alumno@google.com
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=123456
    volumes:
      - ./pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
      - ./pgadmin:/certs/server.cert
      - ./pgadmin:/certs/server.key
      - ./pgadmin:/pgadmin4/servers.json

I need to use port 5433 for this connection, as port 5432 is already being used by PostgreSQL on my PC.
Here is the logs of the container:
2024-05-18 12:17:09 
2024-05-18 12:17:09 PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
2024-05-18 12:17:09 
2024-05-18 12:17:09 2024-05-18 16:17:09.672 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.3 (Debian 16.3-1.pgdg120+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
2024-05-18 12:17:09 2024-05-18 16:17:09.672 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2024-05-18 12:17:09 2024-05-18 16:17:09.672 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2024-05-18 12:17:09 2024-05-18 16:17:09.685 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2024-05-18 12:17:09 2024-05-18 16:17:09.698 UTC [29] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-05-18 16:16:54 UTC
2024-05-18 12:17:09 2024-05-18 16:17:09.709 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2024-05-18 12:22:09 2024-05-18 16:22:09.750 UTC [27] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2024-05-18 12:22:09 2024-05-18 16:22:09.804 UTC [27] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 3 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.015 s, sync=0.007 s, total=0.055 s; sync files=2, longest=0.004 s, average=0.004 s; distance=0 kB, estimate=0 kB; lsn=0/19536E0, redo lsn=0/19536A8
2024-05-18 12:43:36 2024-05-18 16:43:36.351 UTC [91] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2024-05-18 12:43:37 2024-05-18 16:43:37.483 UTC [92] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2024-05-18 12:43:38 2024-05-18 16:43:38.965 UTC [93] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet
2024-05-18 12:43:39 2024-05-18 16:43:39.974 UTC [94] LOG:  invalid length of startup packet


Connections between containers always use the standard TCP port numbers; they ignore ports: if they happen to be present.  Configure your database client to use the standard PostgreSQL port 5432.

You need to use myDB as Connection - Host name/Adress value when adding new server at PG Admin. This is because you defined postgres container with myDB service name at your compose file.
While connecting, service name is important, not the container name.

I forgot to post the answer earlier, my apologies for this oversight. The issue was that I was incorrectly using port 5433. The correct port should have been 5432, as the connection is established between the containers, not with my PC directly. In essence, while the Postgres container is using port 5433 on my PC, I need to direct it to port 5432 of the container. This is my understanding of the solution to the problem. If there are any inaccuracies, I welcome any corrections.
... the correct host name was my-database :D

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
